# Sums records inside foreach loop PHP

Tags: php

I'm using php laravel, Lets suppose below `$records` is an array and has only 3 records, the foreach loop will run 3 times.

```
foreach ($records as $record) {
// Here im using query to get logs against each record id.
$logs = "SELECT delivery, COUNT(*) as logs FROM logs where id = 
$record['id] group by delivery"; 

// Run query and it returns array
var_dump($logs)


}
```

This dump query gets records like this..

1st time

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'delivery' => string '0' (length=1)
      'logs' => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'delivery' => string '1' (length=1)
      'logs' => string '1' (length=1)
```

2nd time

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'delivery' => string '1' (length=1)
      'logs' => string '1' (length=1)
```

3rd time

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'delivery' => string '0' (length=1)
      'logs' => string '1' (length=1)

  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'delivery' => string '1' (length=1)
      'logs' => string '1' (length=1)
```

I want to calculate records like

- Total SMS; // In above example, total are 5
- Total Delivered; // In    above example, Delivered are 3
- Total Failed: // In above example,    Failed are 2

Here is how i'm calculating
If delivery = 0 , it means failed, if delivery = 1, it means delivered, So there are 3 delivered and 2 failed in above scenario.

Here is what i have tried but it not giving me correct result.

```
$logsSENT = $logsFailed = 0;
                    foreach ($logs as $log) {
                        if($log['delivery'] == 1) {
                            $logsSENT +=  $log['logs'] * $smsConsumedPerMessage;
                        }

                        if($log['delivery'] == 0) {
                            $logsFailed +=  $log['logs'] * $smsConsumedPerMessage;
                        }
                    }

$total_sms += $logsSENT + $logsFailed;
```

BTW `'logs' => string '1' (length=1)` Logs value can be more than 1, It can be 2, 3 etc..

Secondly, In my IFs I'm multiplying it with 1 for example
`$logsSENT = $logs[1]['logs'] * 1;` 1 is only for above example, It can be changed later to 2, 3 etc

Comment: You may be better off using another `foreach()` to loop over any records returned and this would simplify your code.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$array = array(
    array(
        array("delivery" => 0, "logs" => 1),
        array("delivery" => 1, "logs" => 1)
    ),
    array(
        array("delivery" => 1, "logs" => 1)
    ),
    array(
        array("delivery" => 0, "logs" => 1),
        array("delivery" => 1, "logs" => 1)
    )
);

$sum = $deliver = $failed = 0;
foreach ($array as $value) {

    $i=$j=1;
    foreach ($value as $va) {
        if($va['delivery']) {
            $deliver = $deliver + $i;
            $i++;
        } else {
            $failed = $failed + $j;
            $j++;
        }
    }
}
echo 'Total:' .($deliver + $failed).'<br>';
echo 'Deliver: '.$deliver.'<br>';
echo 'Failed: '.$failed.'<br>';

?>
```

Comment: It didn't work, BTW logs can be more than 1 for example : "logs" => 2 // can be 2, 3 5.. and in my code, Im also multiplying with 1. `$logsSENT = $logs[1]['logs'] * 1;` i can multiple with 2 and 3 too later.

Comment: base on what you will multiplying but in your question u didn't mention this you just talk about get sum. Please clarify your question

Comment: base on log multiplication how u can get accepted result

Comment: Im multiplying it with 1, for excepted result in above scenario